# Creating SCORM content on the fly

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

I wish to create SCORM packages on the fly i.e. programmatically in ASP.NET so as to run em in some SCORM compliant player on my web, dynamically. I am new to SCORM and have googled about it. What EXACTLY should be inside the SCORM package? I know i'll have to zip the files Im thinking about using System.IO.Packaging namespace classes or maybe someother external library for zipping files. What exactly should inside be in the SCORM package so as to make it SCORM 2.0 complaint and run it in some SCORM player?

Please help..
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need at a minimum 2 things to create a SCORM package:
- A file called imsmanifest.xml that contains the description of the package. This should conform to the SCORM CAM specifications. However, if you only intend to create and run this SCO package dynamically n your player, it may be possible to skip this. 
- A JavaScript API that discovers your SCORM player and calls its functions, LMSInitialize, LMSCommit and LMSFinish at least.

Keep in mind that there is currently no SCORM 2.0. There's only 1.2 and 2004 versions. I strongly suggest that you start with SCORM 1.2 which is simpler and widespread.

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped, though I managed to find the answers before im still marking this as the correct answer. Just one more question, I intend to use SLK which exposes SCORM player. I will be using that to run my scorm content. HOW can I save and FETCH results back from the LMS once I store some result in LMS somehow. Will be vey thankful if you could direct me in the right path - Thanks in advance, Regards

Comment: Although I haven't used SLK myself, all SCORM players behave the same way: You send data using the LMSSetValue() method and you retrieve data by sending the LMSGetValue() method. There is a detailed list of what can be get and set using these at the SCORM RTE book. For example, if you needed to set the "lesson_status" value, you would do a LMSSetValue("lesson_status", "completed"). Similarly, you would do a LMSGetValue("lesson_status") to retrieve a previously set value. Don't forget to call LMSCommit() if you need to persist values with the player

Answer (score 4):

SCORM packages should be self-contained and able to be run just be placing them on the file system of the web server of the LMS. Most LMS's will not allow you to include server side code because it represents a security vulnerability.

If your content needs server-side code, you will need to host it on your own servers, but you will quickly run into the cross domain scripting problem which prevents content in one domain from communicating via JavaScript with an LMS in a different domain.

There are many other specifics of what needs to go into a SCORM package. The best place to start learning about them is to go read [SCORM Explained](http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/) and go through the [Technical SCORM](http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/) track.

Comment: Sir thankyou for answering, But how do I create my own SCORM conformant content?