# How to create SCORM content for php app

Tags: php, package, scorm, scorm2004, scorm1.2

> SCORM is basically a set of standards to be followed for eLearning
>   courses that can track user info during its interaction.

For running a SCO package we need to create it, I am at the very initial stage of LMS development so I would like to know that how do I create an SCORM package for my app.

I read this - [Make_a_single_HTML_page_to_be_a_SCO](http://doc.claroline.net/en/index.php/How_do_I_create_SCORM_content?#Make_a_single_HTML_page_to_be_a_SCO) but this require Dreamweaver and I on Ubuntu (also this is not a general reference).

I also followed this link http://www.elml.org/website/en/html/output_cp.html#d8e3988.html but lost.

Read this one too [Creating SCORM content on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385413/creating-scorm-content-on-the-fly) but not fruitful content.

Please let me know what I am missing for creating a SCORM package as very less content available for the topic.

FYI - I checked http://scorm.com/ but it is a paid solution after 100MB and my app is not a `Moodle` application.

An example or two would really be great at this time.

**EDIT**-

> I posted this question in a very early stage of my exploration for
>   Scorm content.
>
> PIPWERKS CLEARLY ANSWERED THE QUESTION IN GENERAL CONTEXT SO IF YOU
>   CAME ACROSS THIS QUESTION PLEASE READ HIS ANSWER AS WELL.

Comment: Any specific reason for down voting?

Comment: there are literally hundreds of free scorm courses/examples online. one of the resources you mention (scorm.com) has plenty of free examples.  development environment has no bearing on scorm compatibility (scorm is HTML and JavaScript). please ask a real question.

Comment: @pipwerks can you please share the FREE link from where we can create SCORM packages ?? [Im using Ubuntu this time]

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=scorm+examples  First two hits: scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/golf-examples and www.adlnet.gov/scorm/scorm-2004-4th‎. Both have free examples and even the official conformance tests for LMSs, which is presumably what you need to test a homegrown LMS. It took less than 60 seconds to find these.

Comment: and your line "FYI - I checked http://scorm.com/ but it is a paid solution after 100MB and my app is not a Moodle application" has no bearing on creation of SCORM content. SCORM Cloud is a hosting service, not a content creation service. The 100MB limit has nothing to do with creating courses. the line was copied verbatim from your other post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059776/integration-of-scorm-with-php-yii/18075202#18075202, which shows a real lack of effort.

Comment: @pipwerks thx but i think you missed my First line `Practically I am new to SCORM implementation in PHP.` you might be a code ninja but I am not what I did and what I came across I just mentioned here...and that SURELY not suggested that i posted my query randomly and without any efforts

Comment: No, you described how you can't find any information. I responded with two examples I found via google in less than 60 seconds. This has nothing to do with being a code ninja. The quality of your question is poor. I do not wish to chat with you, I have pointed you to the resources you need.

Comment: @pipwerks I dont want to extend my arguments with you but I checked that as well and just looking at the JAVA code doesn't means any how that u can grasp the concept of building a project in JAVA(it is just an example not line on the rock) I do read the document as well what adlnet provided and I was confused with the concept.(sorry to say but i haven't seen such an arrogant person before on stack..still sorry for my words)

Comment: swapnesh: I do not wish to argue, and I'm sorry you feel I'm being arrogant (not my intention). I am simply frustrated because the quality of your question is poor. You have a large enough rep that I would expect a clear, direct _programming_ question. You asked me why I downvoted then attacked my response. I pointed you to the resources you need, then you spurn them as not helpful. I have been reasonable (though perhaps not friendly). I do not wish to spend any more effort on this, it is not helpful for either of us. I have provided a clear, reasonable answer to your question below. Good luck

Comment: @pipwerks aah I missed this comment..and I am very sorry but again thank you for spending your time and answering the question...Now after few days I do feel that the quality of question is not up to the mark ..I need to spend some more time in exploring so that quality questions will remain at the stack...I am very sorry for the comments as well..ur quite senior to me in terms of knowledge and exp...so hope you discard my remarks as a child remarks :) have a good time :) I mentioned you in my question as well now :)

Comment: @swapnesh https://scormhero.com/#/  using this site you can simply convert  ppt file into scrom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too am running Ubuntu and I understand your difficulties, I have yet to find an application that exports scorm. Whenever I needed to create SCORM content myself, I:

1. Created a Windows virtual machine
2. Installed Articulate's storyline demo (free for 30 days)

Articulate products, along with Composica and Adobe Captivate, are perhaps the most popular SCORM content creation applications, so it would be a bonus if your implementation worked nice with them

Doing a quick search in [articulate forums](http://community.articulate.com/forums/p/1070/4145.aspx), I found a sample SCORM 1.2 file you can use, [Big Brute LMS Version](http://upload.articulate.com/2009/BigBrute_daily_demo_SCORM_12-20090804-1211.zip)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge :) can you please add some example/code how a package looks like so that I can actually have an understanding what its going to be in the package to be packed as SCO

Comment: @swapnesh I updated the answer with a link to a file you can download. Remember to start with SCORM 1.2, rather than 2004 (which is more complicated and less popular)

Answer (score 14):

SCORM courses are required to use client-side code; server-side languages such as PHP and ASP are not allowed within the course.

Your headline is "How to create SCORM content for php app". SCORM courses are purposely unaware of what language the LMS is using to load and play the SCORM content. Your LMS can be built in PHP, ASP, Ruby, node.js, etc. Regardless of what language the *player* uses, the *course content* MUST be plain HTML and JavaScript, per spec. (You can include other client-side technologies such as Flash, but HTML and JavaScript are still the core.)

Therefore your headline would be better written as "how do I create SCORM content?" (which is equivalent to "how do I create a SCORM course?").

There are many, many, many examples of SCORM courses online. You can start by copying one of those and modifying it to your needs. As they say, "Google is your friend", so I won't list all of the resources for you. The top Google hits are http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/golf-examples and http://www.adlnet.gov/scorm/scorm-2004-4th

Both of these sites are considered the best resources by SCORM developers.

Keep in mind there are also different editions of SCORM: SCORM 1.2 and SCORM 2004. SCORM 1.2 is considered easier because it has less moving parts. SCORM 2004 is the successor to SCORM 1.2 and is more powerful, but also has a steeper learning curve.

If you simply need SCORM courses for testing your PHP app, the Rustici Golf examples (the scorm.com link) are the absolute best examples you will find. The ADL site includes a conformance checker designed specifically for testing SCORM support in LMSs, so it would be a good idea to use it, as well.

Comment: Hi @pipwerks, I just wanted to take this opportunity and thank you for your js/as libraries. You're the best :)